# Скрыть раздел каталога битрикс

Tags: битрикс

[image: скрин]

Добрый день, в блоке мерчендайз выводятся разделы каталога товаров, как мне скрыть блок продукция, чтобы он не отображался на данной странице?
И как в блоке диджитал-продукция сделать загрузку файлов через инфоблок? Какой параметр отвечает за скачивание?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)